# Newline in tooltip isn't working on Google chrome, but works on Firefox

Tags: html

Basically, the title. I've used following code:

```html
<input type="search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title='Tooltip text 1 &#013;Tooltip text 2'>
```

Comment: Working for me in Chrome

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Still isn't for me. However I found a solution to just update it onpageload by setting the value again with JS. Weird..